# Why i have a diffrence between code size in arm-none-eabi-size, output.map file and arm-none-eabi-nm?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, elf, stm32

In my ARM STM32 project(Eclipse and Gcc) output of command `arm-none-eabi-size` is

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 103784     232   75064  179080   2bb88 project.elf
```

To check code size I tried also diffrent approach. I have opened `output.map`, analyzed it and sumed up .text section, .bss section, .data section etc. Suprisingly I've received diffrent code summary

```
# Sections :
-----------------------
comment  :  8323  bytes.
igot  :  0  bytes.
debug_ranges  :  17208  bytes.
text  :  277702  bytes.
rodata  :  6048  bytes.
eh_frame  :  4  bytes.
fini  :  12  bytes.
iplt  :  0  bytes.
debug_frame  :  76068  bytes.
group  :  29528  bytes.
jcr  :  4  bytes.
debug_line  :  518087  bytes.
debug_macro  :  4878468  bytes.
init  :  12  bytes.
rel  :  0  bytes.
fini_array  :  8  bytes.
debug_str  :  13228775  bytes.
debug_info  :  334376  bytes.
preinit_array  :  0  bytes.
bss  :  143413  bytes.
debug_abbrev  :  52355  bytes.
isr_vector  :  912  bytes.
data  :  451  bytes.
init_array  :  8  bytes.
debug_aranges  :  8248  bytes.
```

So my third approach was to check code size based on `arm-none-eabi-eabi-nm -S --size-sort --radix=d project.elf` output. I've sumed each 'tT', 'dD', 'wW' etc. sections and results are third time diffrent than `arm-none-eabi-size` and `output.map`.

Who to belive? How to read these files(project.elf, output.map) to have real code size, memory usage etc. Maybe there is another way to achive this. I mean for example analyze binary file project.bin?

P.S. Probably you think what i want to achive. My company want to add  new  library to project. I have to check how much binary file will be bigger with these library and check memory usage, static and dynamic allocation. I need to have reliable results of code sections size to check it.

Comment: yes look at the binary file although it may be padded between the flash and ram addresses.  Or do a disassembly (arm-whatever-objdump -D file.elf) and then examine what is really in those sections and what is debug info, perhaps compare side by side with what is in the binary to see what is not really used.

Comment: could also strip the elf file and see what changes, might get more clear.

Comment: binary file or uC resources consumption?